# iPhone: Find out where am I when application is in background

Tags: iphone, background, geolocation

I can get the current location of my iPhone but I was wondering if it is possible to call my methods when application is in background and pop-up message(may be using local notification?) if user has reached at particular location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. A local notification is also an excellent solution.

All you need to do is to set the flags for background position updates in the app plist. Then, in the callback methods for the location manager, perform the distance and/or location tracking logging and fire a local notification.